# How to properly parse strings with arrayformula() with a regexextract() to them sum() them?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a range of columns that may or may not have symbols after a numeral (e.g. 3, 4, 2++, 1-) and my goal is to strip any non-number characters and provide a sum of the whole shebang.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT($B$21:$I$21, "[0-9]+"))
```

The above gives me an appropriate list of cells (continuing the above examples, I'd get the following values in separate cells: 3, 4, 2, 1).

Now when I try and sum it up I get an error or it just plain gives me 0 as the result.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT($B$21:$I$21, "[0-9]+")))
```

and

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(REGEXEXTRACT($B$21:$I$21, "[0-9]+")))
```

Both return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex converts numbers to text strings so you need to do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(REGEXEXTRACT($B$21:$I$21&"", "[0-9]+")*1))
```